# Efficient Table Generation & NDSolve Error

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, warning-messages

I'm currently working on solving an SEIR model with data from the CDC. I've created a function to calculate the Square difference for the model and want to create a table of values for the 4 variable combinations, along with their Goodness of fit characteristic from the square difference.

I'm getting this alert when running the function:
"*NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is recommended.*"

It sounds like something I could ignore, but I don't want to mess anything up by doing so.

Also... the big question. Is there any recommendations to make creating this table of values more efficient rather than waiting a half hour for this to work itself out?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

CDCdata = {{0, 161}, {1, 197}, {2, 298}, {3, 339}, {4, 409}, {5, 
614}, {6, 848}, {7, 1359}, {8, 1985}, {9, 3346}, {10, 4590}, {11, 
5938}, {12, 6511}, {13, 6514}, {14, 6952}, {15, 5982}, {16, 
5167}, {17, 4077}, {18, 3126}, {19, 2457}, {20, 2136}, {21, 
1848}, {22, 1680}, {23, 1497}, {24, 1269}, {25, 1007}, {26, 
898}, {27, 644}, {28, 459}, {29, 380}};

ListPlot[CDCdata]

p = Interpolation[CDCdata];
Plot[p[t], {t, 0, 29}]

Population = 20328;
Squarediff[Mu_, Beta_, Alpha_, 
  Nu_] := (sol = 
   First@NDSolve[{s'[t] == 
       Mu*Population - Mu*s[t] - Beta*(i[t]/Population)*s[t], 
      e'[t] == Beta*(i[t]/Population)*s[t] - (Mu + Alpha) e[t], 
      i'[t] == Alpha*(e[t]) - (Nu + Mu)*(i[t]), 
      r'[t] == Nu*i[t] - Mu*r[t],
      i[0] == 161,
      s[0] == 20328,
      r[0] == 0, e[0] == 0},
     {s, e, i, r}, {t, 0, 29}]; 
  Sum[(((CDCdata[[j, 2]] - i[CDCdata[[j, 1]]]) /. sol)^2), {j, 1, 
    Length[CDCdata]}])

values = Flatten[
   Table[{{a, b, c, d}, Squarediff[a, b, c, d]}, {a, 0, 0.0005, 
     0.00001}, {b, 0, 0.2, 0.01}, {c, 0, 0.1, 0.01}, {d, 0, 0.1, 
     0.01}], 1];
```

Comment: What about [Beta](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Beta.html?q=Beta&lang=en)?

Comment: Don't create symbols that start with a capital letter as those might shadow/conflict with Mathematica defined symbols. In your case `Beta` is a Mathematica defined function!

Comment: @Artes are you trying to say the same thing as the comment below?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

`ParametricNDSolveValue` may be a useful way to explore the parameter space and then you can quantify goodness of fit. Using the same definitions as your original post (with change of variables):

```
fun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{s'[t] == 
    mu*Population - mu*s[t] - beta*(i[t]/Population)*s[t], 
   e'[t] == beta*(i[t]/Population)*s[t] - (mu + alpha) e[t], 
   i'[t] == alpha*(e[t]) - (nu + mu)*(i[t]), 
   r'[t] == nu*i[t] - mu*r[t], i[0] == 161, s[0] == 20328, r[0] == 0, 
   e[0] == 0}, {s, e, i, r}, {t, 0, 29}, {mu, beta, alpha, nu}]
```

This creates set of interpolating functions for: susceptible, infected etc. As you are interested in `i[t]` this is the third function. You can dynamically explore the parameter space ( I have put the funcion p[t] as the reference):

```
Manipulate[Module[{foi},
  foi = fun[a, b, c, d][[3]];
  Plot[{foi[t], p[t]}, {t, 0, 29}]],
 {{a, 0.001, μ}, 0.001, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 0.01, β}, 0.01, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, 0.01, α}, 0.01, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{d, 0.01, ν}, 0.01, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]

Not rigorous but a starting point. This may narrow the parameter space and you can calculate or use other methods to find best fit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've changed the variable names. The issue I have now is, I want to get all 4 variable names a bit more accurate. By changing the step size in the `values` table, I increase the calculation time by a ton. It ran over night and still isn't done. Any recommendations?

Comment: @KevinMurphy see edit